# Looking for C# library that provides/contains performance analytics

Tags: returns, performance-evaluation, performanceanalytics, programming

I am looking for a C# .Net library that provides trade performance analytics similar to R-PerformanceAnalytics. Basic return statistics, draw-downs, risk-adjusted returns, risk (variations), distributional analytics,...

I checked all the general Math/Stats C# libraries and I can certainly whip up analytics from several such libraries but something that covers more specific financial asset return analysis did not come across my search.

Even basic trade analytics such as risk/reward, MAR, MAE/MFE, drawdowns would be helpful, just to generate some quick stats for a side-project.

Edit: I am not interested in a R solution as I am already aware of the R PerformanceAnalytics package. I am looking for a C# library, commercial or open-source.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered [R.NET](http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/)? I don't know anything about it, other than it exists...

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich, I am familiar with the library and have coded against it but at this point I rather like to perform all computations natively in C# or else export the dataset (most likely through Redis)  and run the analytics in R. At the moment I prefer to run within C# only. R.NET is good at running a couple commands but shipping larger datasets through the API seems very slow.

Comment: You can offer as much of a bounty as you want; the fact remains is that the code you want is *there in R* so if I were you I'd look into RServe or other means to accessing R remotely if you really insist on sticking to C#/CLR/Windoze.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, nobody disputed that a package for R exists and I acknowledge your expertise on the R side (among most likely other, to me unknown, areas) . But I think I made clear that I look for a C# library, not an R package. I am a bit irritated why the condescending tone, if you do not know of such library or dislike Windows or .Net for that matter, why having to comment?

Comment: There is a saying that "wishing alone does not make it so" and my post basically paraphrased it.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel, slightly bizarre is all I can say. Not sure whether you would also convince your coworkers or bosses to use 2-3 detours to force them into R when a Java or C++ solution is asked for. PerformanceAnalytics is a great R package if I wanted to use pure R. But to ship a large time series across the .Net-R interface and having to wait literally an eternity just does not make it feasable for me to go this route.

Comment: Don't take it all that personally. It is essentially a wager; let's revisit when the bounty is up.  Maybe you will have someone pointing you to something; my money is still on that being rather unlikely.

Comment: ...but by all means if you think your suggestion is the best you can think of feel free to write up a 1-2 liner as answer...it is definitely A way to solve the question at hand.

Comment: Fair enough. We use Rserve at work to connect to a Windows machine running a particular service which can run only on Windows. You have the inverse, and I would like into Windows clients for Rserve. There are a few around.

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about. R is not the right solution for me and I would only go this route if there is no other alternative and here is why: It takes more than 10 seconds to send a simple array/vector with 1,000,000 elements through R.NET. On the other hand the Rserve C# client comes out of the box with runtime errors. Unfortunate but very typical experience for me with many packages and extensions regarding R. The big issue is that a lot of this stuff is not peer reviewed and more often than not packages contain serious bugs.

Comment: ...and running the accompanied sample code and having to deal with runtime errors is a show stopper for me, meaning the library is either hopelessly outdated or the library was coded up in a sloppy fashion. (And yes, I configured RServe correctly). I rest my case with this, if RServe works for you then all the more power to you.

Comment: You are barking up the wrong tree. I don't use either C# or Windows, so I have not bone in this fight -- my money is on C++ with R on Linux.  But as you asked, yes, thanks, between Linux and Windows Rserve works fine, modulo the lack of fork() in Windows meaning that there can be only one connection.

Comment: Dirk, I think you should contain yourself a little, you are getting offensive. Given that a number of investment banks nowadays run whole exotic option pricing engines on Windows Servers, that most tier 1 bank pricing library's language of choice is C# nowadays, that many of the new front-ends are served via WPF guis does not lend much credibility to your arguments. You are the only one who sounds furious that I am not embracing R, and I have no idea why you would care. I told you already I wont use R and if I do not find a better solution then I ...

Comment: ...will write my own library. I am almost convinced that is the best way anyway because performing most performance algorithms during time-series building run-time is computationally way more efficient than doing so on top of completed time series. I think your rude and condescending attitude to those who wrote up the two answers is out of place, especially given that you could not even write up your own two lines of answer, either because you have a beef with me or for whatever other reason. I do use R, but not for this project, hope this makes it clear now.

Comment: And I can only repeat to invite you to offer your own answer. I agree that the other two currently standing two answers do not solve my problem and I would chose your suggestion via R because it tackles the issue at hand. Do it for the community not for me if you have such issues with my "sound and fury" (your words that you subsequently deleted)

Comment: I can't stop giggling about your claim that everybody uses C# now. Everywhere I look C# has been abandoned for anything but GUIs, but beauty is as always in eye of the beholder.

Comment: I never claimed "everybody", and certainly I exaggerated when I said "most" but maybe you want to inquire with SocGen and BNP, just two houses out of several others. They both run their pricing engines on Windows Server and the C++ libraries have been dumped and been replaced with C# as far as I heard. And who abandoned C# libraries? What have they been replaced with? Eddelbuettel's Top10 R-packages? ;-) Dirk, its hard to take someone serious who apparently seems "stuck" in a let's-hate-Microsoft can.

Comment: I rest my case, fact remains that slowly more and more financial C++ libraries are being replaced, and the most popular language of replacement on the sell-side is C#. You have a right to vehemently disagree, but for that I recommend you to write a post on your own blog or website. You have made your recommendation re my question clear and I respect that. Let's move on...

Comment: Same here. I work in the industry too, and I can assure you that C# is _not_ a growing trend over where I work (besides surviving for GUIs).  But we all have our preferences, and if you like it, good for you. That case is closed, now let's see how you can best access something already provided in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, thanks to Dirk Eddelbuettel's suggestion I played a bit with rredis and indeed it offers quite a number interesting solutions.

However, I still decided to start to write my own performance analytics library (albeit obviously smaller and more specific to my use case) in combination with an established Math/Stats library because I need more fine-grained performance attribution metrics, such as sliding lookback windows, custom distributional assumptions, different formulaic approach to measuring risk-adjusted returns for trades of extremely short holding periods...

Having delved a bit more into parallel execution in R and understanding how to run several R sessions on a single machine or in distributed fashion explains why there is no real need/demand to equip a single R session with multithreaded capabilities. Credits to Dirk and his pointing me into the rredis and indirectly to the distributed workload processing direction in R. I so far heavily rely on a fully customized research platform and Matlab and thus have not done a whole lot with R. I left when R still could not handle larger datasets and when there was no 64-bit version available (at least not for Windows), which kind of defeated the whole purpose to peruse a statistical computing platform from the start (at least for someone working with larger time series data). Obviously, quite a number of things have changed and it is interesting to see the explosion in growth of use cases and packages such as adapters that connect R with various data stores, other libraries, languages, ...

Answer (score 3):

The [PerformanceAnalytics](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=PerformanceAnalytics) library reflects several years worth of development by Brian Peterson and Peter Carl, as well as multiple collaborators.  It is fairly widely used, tested and debugged.

Basic software engineering practices suggest that you should strive to re-use it if possible.  Options for that include

- accessing a remote R instance via [RServe](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/) (though you may be unhappy with the state of RServe clients on Windows / C# as per your comments)
- accessing a remote R instance via a RESTful service such as [OpenCPU](https://www.opencpu.org/)
- placing your jobs on a queue (for which I like Redis) and having the R worker pick'em up from the queue via [rredis](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=rredis)

The last option is the loosest coupling and may be easiest to test.  I would rather go down any of these routes than trying to rewrite [PerformanceAnalytics](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=PerformanceAnalytics). Don't forget that the package itself has dependencies you may have to port as well.

Comment: I did not say that I intend to rewrite any library, I only plan to peruse a fraction of the functionality that PerformanceAnalytics offers. I like your last bullet point suggestion, because I heavily use Redis as key/value store and for pub/sub though I have never worked with rredis. I assume rredis is some sort of workload forwarder or would I need to write the workload client myself in R? +voted

Comment: You probably should just read the documentation of the [rredis package](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=rredis) but the "tl;dr" version is that it is the main Redis package for R.

Comment: And as you asked: we also just released the [RcppRedis](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=RcppRedis) package which should have Windows binaries in a few days, hopefully.  But it has a _much_ narrower scope.

Comment: I posted a question on stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672491/doredis-causes-names-attribute-69-must-be-the-same-length-as-the-vector-68) because I am getting errors when executing a simple example regarding doRedis. Is doRedis even the right package to use if I just want to have a single worker that picks up commands from the redis queue and stores the results back on redis? I am asking because doRedis seems to really zero in on distributed workload processing through foreach loops. Any hints? Thanks

Comment: No, doRedis is particular to the foreach parallel framework. I would use rredis as I had suggested earlier.

Comment: I see that, but I fail to see how I can perform automated command processing off redis queues with rredis. Is my assumption correct that I would have to write the listener and processor myself?

Comment: Yes. I am not aware of generic Redis queue processor for R. Should just be a few commands to get started.  The doRedis example can give you ideas -- just "LPOP" and then execute, or something similar.

Comment: that itself would not be the issue, I just wonder whether there is a simple way in R to execute "string commands". I think I could use `Parse` and `Eval`...?

Comment: Are you looking for system() or eval()?

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me into the rredis direction and indirectly into how to distribute workloads using different R sessions. I have not used R for quite some time as explained in my own answer, but have to admit that especially the capability to distribute workload through multiple R sessions opens up a whole load of new opportunities. Yet, for this specific project I still decided to write my own customized solution (also explained in my own answer). But that in no way diminishes my appreciation for walking me and other users through the options available to connect with R.